# Android: Map size of one activity takes the map size of another activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-mapview, android-maps

In My Map project , I have a map which occupies whole screen of the device in Main Activity. And I have some pins on the Map. If we press the pin ,it will lead to another Activity. There I have a map whose size is one third of the screen size. If we come to Main Activity from the another activity.

**The Map in the Main Activity takes the size of Map in the another activity.**

My Main activity xml is
<

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/submit"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:text="Search" />
    </LinearLayout>



    <com.xxx.yyy.FireMapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:apiKey="xxxxxxxxxxx"
        android:clickable="true" >
    </com.xxx.yyy.FireMapView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And My another activity xml is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/reportentry"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.xxx.yyy.FireMapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:apiKey="xxxxxx"
        android:clickable="true" >
    </com.xxx.yyy.FireMapView>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/reportentry1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/a1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/add"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Address" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/address"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ft1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ft2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="ft" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/ft3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/c"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/c1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="C" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/c2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
               />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/p1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/p2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="p" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/p3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fc"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fc1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="fc" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/fc2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/btn_info"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cancel"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Cancel" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/report"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Report" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Please provide me the correct way....

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per docs android maintains one mapview instance  per process. So, you can't maintain different mapview instances in single process.

If size is only your problem then while coming back to to your mainactivity call

```
mapView.getController.zoomIn();

mapView.getController.zoomOut();
```

in onRestart() of mainactivity.

It's not perfect solution but at least it worked for me.

This issue was already reported http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3756